# Why does Remote Desktop struggle with DPI settings so much?

Tags: remote-desktop, dpi

I run a QHD (2k) display with a DPI of 125%. It works with RDP sessions but it is so clunky when you connect - it can take a good 30s for each window to be adjusted, you can see it happening one by one.

Is this a fundmamental limitation in RDP or might I be able to make some settings changes?

Comment: This is not an RDP issue, it's a Windows + app issue - in particular, the display driver 
+ window manager needs to adjust the DPI for all open windows (the apps are probably open at a different DPI setting) and the apps need to adjust to the new DPI.

Comment: @cdavid well in my case I'm the only one connecting to that machine. But if I disconnect or lose connection briefly, it does the same clumsy resizing every time. I wonder why the windows reset to 100% DPI like this?